# Invert Y-Axis Water Spray in Super Mario Sunshine

Tags: dolphin-emulator, super-mario-sunshine

So what I want to to be able to do is flip the Y-axis in the water spray mode in Super Mario Sunshine.
I am running the game with Dolphin and am using a gamepad. I do have it set up and have inverted the camera X-axis already.

Running around is fine, but the spaying water, just....
Up is up. Down is down.
I'm not flying an airplane, why are these controls "backwards"?

I could invert the Y-axis controls on the Control Stick but then to run forward I'd have to be pulling the sick backwards. Ridiculous; this would make platforming a memory hell.

I'm hoping there is a way to open the game files and change one little value for the water controls...
Or a mod I can install or something, But I'm not finding anything.

Comment: I don't believe Dolphin has any specific functionality that could help with this. Maybe it could be done with a custom AR cheat? It would need to be a pretty complicated code.

Comment: I figure the only way around this problem has to be either a mod or altering the game files, since there is that contradiction of controls in the game files. 
However, I could set it up to use the control pad to move, having the directions proper, and the stick inverted for spraying, I might try that but using the control pad always sucks imo.

Answer (score 5):

It may be possible to do with an action replay. However, if you are using an emulator (presumable Dolphin) you can achieve this using the following steps:

If you are using a Gamecube controller, make sure your adapter is set to PC instead of Wii U.

Right click on Controller Stick Up, and add the following:
([your input for backward] & !([your input for R])) | ([Your input for forward] & [your input for R])

Then, right click on Controller Stick Down, and add the following:
([your input for forward] & !([your input for R])) | ([Your input for backward] & [your input for R])

Answer (score 3):

You can invert Up and Down only when R is fully pressed. This will allow you to spray while running by half pressing the R trigger, just like the original Gamecube controller.

An example (full press threshold = 90%):

Up:

```
(`Left Y+` & (`Trigger R` < 0.9)) | (`Left Y-` & (`Trigger R` > 0.9))
```

Down:

```
(`Left Y-` & (`Trigger R` < 0.9)) | (`Left Y+` & (`Trigger R` > 0.9))
```

[image]

Answer (score -5):

Sadly, there is no way to achieve what you are proposing. The game settings itself do not give you the opportunity to change the axis' of movement while spraying and changing the game files itself would be illegal as you would be changing Nintendo's intellectual properties.

On a different note, I am certain you are playing using a legal copy you obtained by ripping your own game disc to an iso.

Comment: If they *are* playing with an emulator they could potentially remap the controls using a third party application

Comment: I have used a button mapper in the past but I believe that it would be pointless since the Water gun and movement control are the same.