# Super Mario Sunshine Camera Inversion

Tags: dolphin-emulator, super-mario-sunshine

I'm using Dolphin Master Branch emulator for Super Mario Sunshine. Game works and everything, but I want to change the camera inversion for spraying.

I tried following the instructions from this answer: [Invert Y-Axis Water Spray in Super Mario Sunshine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/309102/invert-y-axis-water-spray-in-super-mario-sunshine)

But the syntax failed:

1. `Left Y+`
   Works as intended
2. (`Left Y+` & (`Trigger R` < 0.99)) | (`Left Y-` & (`Trigger R` > 0.99))
   Syntax error
3. (`Left Y+` & (`Trigger R > 0.99`)) | (`Left Y+` & (`Trigger R < 0.99`))
   2 bound controls, but Up doesn't work for either.
4. `Left Y+` & `Trigger R > 0.99` | `Left Y+` & `Trigger R < 0.99'
   Same thing. I found out that I can insert those apostrophes anywhere and no errors will be detected.
5. `Left Y+` & `Trigger R > 0.99` | `Left Y+` & `Trigger R < 0.99'
   Same thing.
6. `Left Y+` & `Trigger R > 0.99'
   This is also recognized as a valid control, but Up still doesn't work.

Nothing seems to work without a syntax error, or the emulator just isn't able to recognize what I am trying to do.